# Removing an specific object from an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I need help removing a specific object from an arraylist. I'm creating objects with a unique ID and grade for each object.I'm trying to use this unique ID to remove an object from the arraylist, but am having trouble figuring out why my code isn't working. I have my main Driver class, a superclass, and a subclass.

The subclass is where the object information is passed from and extends the superclass. I thought that since the subclass is extended, it would be able to be defined from there.

The problem that is occurring is line 49 of the superclasss. Eclipse says that getStudentID isn't defined in the class.

I am trying to modify code that my instructor provided in order to locate this unique ID that an object in the arraylist has. I believe I did everything correctly, but the method "locationPerson" doesn't seem to see the getStudentID() method in the subclass.

Here is the code. Any help would be appreciated!

**Subclass**

```
public class StudentEnrollee extends ClassSection{
    private int grade;
    private String studentID;

    StudentEnrollee() {
        setStudentID("000-000");
        setGrade(0);
    }

    StudentEnrollee(String ID, int theGrade) {
        setStudentID(ID);
        setGrade(0);
    }

//STUDENT ID    
    public String getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(String theStudentID) {
        this.studentID = theStudentID;
    }
//STUDENT GRADE 
    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int studentGrade) {
        this.grade = studentGrade;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return("Student ID   : " + studentID + "\n" +
               "Student Grade: " + grade);

    }


}
```

**Superclass**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ClassSection {

  private int crn, courseNumber, capacity, enrollment, ID, student;
  private String departmentCode, courseMode, meetingDay, meetingTime;
  //CONSTRUCTOR 
  ClassSection() {
    setCrn(0);
    setDepartmentCode("");
    setCourseNumber(0);
    setCourseMode("");
    setMeetingDay("");
    setMeetingTime("");
    setCapacity(0);
    setEnrollment(0);
    setID(0);

  }

  ClassSection(int crn, String departmentCode, int courseNumber, String courseMode, String meetingDay, String meetingTime, int capacity, int enrollment, int ID) {
    setCrn(crn);
    setDepartmentCode(departmentCode);
    setCourseNumber(courseNumber);
    setCourseMode(courseMode);
    setMeetingDay(meetingDay);
    setMeetingTime(meetingTime);
    setCapacity(capacity);
    setEnrollment(enrollment);
    setID(ID);
  }

  //STUDENT ENROLL ARRAY
  List < StudentEnrollee > studentList = new ArrayList < StudentEnrollee > ();

  public int getStudent() {
    return student;
  }
  public void addStudent(StudentEnrollee studentObject) {
      studentList.add(studentObject);
    }
    //LOCATING PERSON
  public ClassSection locatePerson(String getStudentID) {
    for (ClassSection personObject: studentList) {
      if (personObject.getStudentID().equals(getStudentID)) {
        return personObject;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }



  //Delete person
  public void deletePerson(String studentID) {
    ClassSection personObject = locatePerson(studentID); // we'll use our locatePerson method find the index of a Person with a given socSecNum.

    if (personObject != null) studentList.remove(personObject); // if element i contains the target SSN, remove it.

  }

  //DISPLAY LIST OF ENROLLEE    
  public void displayListV1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) // the old way
    {
      System.out.println(studentList.get(i) + "\n");
    }
  }

  //CRN 
  public int getCrn() {
    return crn;
  }

  void setCrn(int classCrn) {
      this.crn = classCrn;
    }
    //DEPARTMENT CODE
  public String getDepartmentCode() {
    return departmentCode;
  }

  void setDepartmentCode(String classDepartmentCode) {
      this.departmentCode = classDepartmentCode;
    }
    //COURSE NUMBER 
  public int getCourseNumber() {
    return courseNumber;
  }

  void setCourseNumber(int classCourseNumber) {
      this.courseNumber = classCourseNumber;
    }
    //COURSE LOCATION
  public String getCourseMode() {
    return courseMode;
  }

  public void setCourseMode(String classCourseMode) {
      this.courseMode = classCourseMode;
    }
    //MEETING DAY
  public String getMeetingDay() {
    return meetingDay;
  }

  public void setMeetingDay(String classMeetingDay) {
      this.meetingDay = classMeetingDay;
    }
    //MEETING TIMES
  public String getMeetingTime() {
    return meetingTime;
  }

  public void setMeetingTime(String classMeetingTime) {
      this.meetingTime = classMeetingTime;
    }
    //CAPACITY
  public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
  }

  public void setCapacity(int classCapacity) {
      this.capacity = classCapacity;
    }
    //ENROLLMENT
  public int getEnrollment() {
    return enrollment;
  }

  public void setEnrollment(int classEnrollment) {
      this.enrollment = classEnrollment;
    }
    //INSTRUCTOR ID
  public int getID() {
    return ID;
  }

  public void setID(int instructorID) {
      this.ID = instructorID;
    }
    //TO STRING METHOD  
  public String toString() {

    return ("CRN                :" + crn + "\n" +
      "Department         :" + departmentCode + "\n" +
      "Course Number      :" + courseNumber + "\n" +
      "Instructional mode :" + courseMode + "\n" +
      "Meeting days       :" + meetingDay + "\n" +
      "Meeting times      :" + meetingTime + "\n" +
      "Capacity           :" + capacity + "\n" +
      "Enrollment         :" + enrollment + "\n" +
      "Instructor’s ID    :" + ID + "\n");

  }
}
```

**Driver**

```
public class ClassDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassSection firstInstance = new ClassSection(20008, "CHM", 000, "Online", "N/A", "N/A", 30, 21, 231);
    ClassSection secondInstance = new ClassSection();
    ClassSection addToList = new ClassSection();

    StudentEnrollee studentObj1 = new StudentEnrollee();
    StudentEnrollee studentObj2 = new StudentEnrollee();
    StudentEnrollee studentObj3 = new StudentEnrollee();

    studentObj1.setGrade(5);
    studentObj1.setID(230);

    studentObj2.setGrade(76);
    studentObj2.setID(45);

    studentObj3.setGrade(2);
    studentObj3.setID(34);


    addToList.addStudent(studentObj1);
    addToList.addStudent(studentObj2);
    addToList.addStudent(studentObj3);

    addToList.deletePerson("45");


    addToList.displayListV1();

    System.out.println(firstInstance.toString());



    System.out.println(secondInstance.toString());


  }

}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code that you have posted.  You might be more likely to get help if you posted only the relevant sections of your code.  Also it would help if you indicated exactly which line is *"line 49 of the superclasss"* as your post does not include line numbers.

Comment: You might consider using a HashSet<String,YourObjectType> where the String is your unique id and the object instance is YourObjectType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
public StudentEnrollee locatePerson(String getStudentID) {
    for (StudentEnrollee personObject: studentList) {
        if (personObject.getStudentID().equals(getStudentID)) {
            return personObject;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You are trying to use a method from subclass in superclass, so you got the error that this method is not defined. You can use all method of superclass in subclasses, but it doesn't work another way.

Comment: That fixed it for me! Thank you very much, I spent about an hour trying to find out what was wrong with it, so very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `getStudentID()` method is declared in class `StudentEnrollee`. In the code below, `personObject`, which is defined as a `ClassSection` object, does not have access to it.

```
public ClassSection locatePerson(String getStudentID) {
    for (ClassSection personObject: studentList) {
        if (personObject.getStudentID().equals(getStudentID)) {
            return personObject;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The solution can vary based on your program logic, but the straightforward way is to replace `ClassSection` with `StudentEnrollee`:

```
public StudentEnrollee locatePerson(String getStudentID) {
    for (StudentEnrollee personObject: studentList) {
        if (personObject.getStudentID().equals(getStudentID)) {
            return personObject;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me!